# How do I keep the Random Value node static on changing geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes, alembic, point-clouds

I have an Alembic point cloud I'm trying to render as grains, but the random size keeps changing every frame because the point count isn't static. I guess I could use the seed input, but I have no idea what seed to use. As far as I know blender can't import Alembic attributes on point clouds yet.

Comment: Just connect the input node `Integer` (with any value) with the input *ID* in the node `Random Value`. This way the randomly generated value remains the same in all frames.

Comment: @quellenform that randomizes everything uniformly i.e. every particle has the same size. I want every particle to have a different, but static, size.

Comment: Then please be so kind and show us a screenshot of your node tree, or even better: share your blend file with us (https://blend-exchange.com/), because otherwise there might be more misunderstandings here. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform this is an example file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/BVk35Ajy , you can see that every particle has the same size. Now, I'm aware that when using Distribute Points node, changing the point count does not change their ID, but this is not true for an Alembic file

Comment: OK, thanks, but this file doesn't really reflect your specific example, because there's no Alembic here. Anyway: What happens if you plug the input node `Index` at *ID* instead of an integer value?

Comment: Ah, wait, I obviously didn't read your question carefully! You write "...point count **is not static**". This means that my suggestions were nonsense. Anyway, without your file (incl. Alembic) it might be hard to help here.